# Moving folder from one location to another in a web service

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a web service that locates files in a folder (C:\Incoming) and emails them to a specified email address.  I want to be able to move that folder, once it has been mailed to another folder (C:\Processed).

I tried using this code below, but it does not work.

```
 string SourceFile = "C:\\Incoming\\" + "" + Year + "" + Month + "" + Day + "";
 string destinationFile = "C:\\Processed" + "" + Year + "" + Month + "" + Day + ""; 
 System.IO.File.Move(SourceFile , destinationFile);
```

I get an error saying that the sourcefile could not be found.  I have verified that it does exist and I have access to it.

Comment: add your file extension at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are moving folders not file you will need to iterate over files to copy one by one.

```
string Source = "C:\\Incoming\\" + "" + Year + "" + Month + "" + Day + "";
string destination = "C:\\Processed" + "" + Year + "" + Month + "" + Day + "";
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Source);
FileInfo[] fileList = di.GetFiles(".*.");
int count = 0;
foreach (FileInfo fi in fileList)
{
    System.IO.File.Move(Source+"\\"+fi.Name , destinationFile+"\\"+fi.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.Format` for one, second use `System.IO.File.Exists()` to make sure the file is there.

```
string SourceFile = String.Format("C:\\Incoming\\{0}{1}{2}",Year,Month,Day);
 string destinationFile = String.Format("C:\\Processed\\{0}{1}{2}",Year,Month,Day);

 if (System.IO.File.Exists(SourceFile) {
     System.IO.File.Move(SourceFile , destinationFile);
 }
```